# Is it possible to see what is subscribed to an AWS SQS queue?

Tags: message-queue, publish-subscribe, amazon-sqs

I'm reverse engineering some code that sends a message to an Amazon SQS queue.  I know the name of the queue, and can find it in the my AWS console.  However, I don't know what is subscribed to the queue.  I'd like to see how the message is being processed.  Is there an easy way to find that?  I can't see anything in the console, or in the CLI... I was hoping for something comparable to rabbitmqctl, which can show you a list of subscribers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't subscribe to an SQS queue.  SQS queues have listeners that poll (usually long-poll) the queue for messages.

Anybody anywhere with valid, authorized credentials possessing the permission to receive messages from the can poll it (or not poll it) at any time.

Queues don't have subscribers -- topics, like in SNS -- have subscribers, where messages are broadcast to all subscribers each time a message is published.

There are several [Cloudwatch metrics for SQS queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQS_metricscollected.html) that you can use to determine *whether* the queue is being polled, but the interactions between listeners and queues is a different model than some other message queue platforms, where listeners to the queue maintain a persistent connection (and can therefore potentially be enumerated).  An SQS listener connects, receives any available messages up to the max allowed or requested, disconnects¹, processes the messag(es), then reconnects to delete the messages (otherwise the messages eventually become visible for another listener to receive... or the same listener... SQS has no concept of "who" is listening, because everything works over HTTP which is, of course, stateless.

---

¹Of course, with HTTP keep-alive, the listener may not technically disconnect the TCP connection to the SQS API endpoint, but there is no state preserved when this happens and SQS has no sense that the listener is "still connected."

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation.